# Python/Django: synonym for field "type" in database model (reserved built-in symbol)

Tags: python, django, model

I created a django project. It contains a model class with a **"type" attribute**. I think that "type" is the most appropriate term to describe that field, because it defines the kind of the  entry.

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        (u'car', u'Car'),
        (u'motorcycle', u'Motorcycle'),
        (u'airplane', u'Airplane'),
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TYPE)
```

I do not like "kind" or "category" that much because they are not as generic as "type".

### The problem

```
Assignment to reserved built-in symbol: type
```

1. This is a warning, so is that a problem?
2. If yes, what choices do i have?
3. Do you have a good alternative to the term "type"?

Comment: `type` is not strictly reserved word, its just not recommended to be used. Also, syntax highlight in editor, Vim for me, would incorrectly highlight it, this is the strongest reason for me not to use it =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. It's always a bad idea to have a variable name that shadows one of
   [python's built-ins](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html). It will confuse people reading your code, who expect type to mean something specific. Less important than readability to other users it can also throw off syntax highlighting.
2. Rename the variable. (really it's the best thing to do  - you could leave it, but rename now while it's easy)
3. There are lots of [potential options](http://thesaurus.com/browse/type?s=t), perhaps `classification` or `category`. I know you said you don't like `category`, but I can't see what's not generic about it?

It might be that it would be overkill for your specific application (would need to know more), but django does support [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

Comment: true. maybe, category is indeed the best choice. also, thanks for giving the pointer to model inheritance

Answer (score 23):

I disagree with the other answers. There's no need to change this.

In my opinion, there is little risk of confusion, as you will never access the attribute except via an instance. `my_vehicle.type` is not easy to confuse with (eg) `type(my_vehicle)`.

Comment: That's true, but it's just so easy to rename now, and there is a wealth of other words to use.

Comment: agreeing with andrew, because this will probably prevent future errors when you or somebody else will look back at the code

Comment: Also he's getting a warning in whatever linter he's using, so his options are to ignore the error (annoying) or add some comment macro to temporarily remove the error (ugly), or turn off the error (bad).

Comment: this is also reasonable, but i agree with Andrew Barret: i want to get rid of that error

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Django creates a field named `id` and `id()` is a Python build-in function. Nobody confuses the two. Same story and no problem.

Comment: **IF** you want to avoid this warning and still use type, according to [pep8 descriptive naming styles](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)  you should use a single trailing underscore (i.e. `type_`).

Answer (score 1):

Well, warning or error, i'd avoid always to risk a situation like yours :) The better thing in my opinion you can do is change the variable name without losing any meaning nor cohesion. You could call it "v_type" meaning vehicle type in a shortened way, if it's used only for that particular class. If you'll extend that class, you'll extend it with another vehicle type, so in your case "v_type" would fit.

Comment: this would work, but "v_type" or "vehicle_type" does not look right to me. then i would have to name all other field in the same kind: "v_name", "v_price", ...

Comment: that is completely up to you :) i tend myself to use the same identifier type for every variable (as you pointed out, v_type "requires" to change also v_name) since you decided for "category", a shortened version "cat" should do the trick, and is also a common variable name used to identify categories (well, common means just i've seen it a lot of times) i liked your post, btw!